# Notepad++ flipping/reordering lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have many instances of the following code block, simplified:

```
$image = '';
$name = '';
$link = '';
$role_suffix = '';
$role_name = '';
$notes = '';
```

All these variables contain different data. I need to turn my file into an array, which I can do with simple search and replace but first I need to switch `$link` with `$image`. Thusly:

```
$link = '';
$name = '';
$image = '';
$role_suffix = '';
$role_name = '';
$notes = '';
```

Surely there must be a regex solution to save manually changing them all? I have tried hacking together answers found in different questions, but the regex makes no sense to me at all! I played around with this `(<div>.*?</div>)(\s+)(<span>.*?</span>)` and replacing with `\3\2\1` but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\$image\h*=\h*.+?;)([\s\S]+?)(\$link\h*=\h*.+?;)`
- Replace with: `$3$2$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # start group 1
    \$image     # literally
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    =           # equal sign
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    ;           # semicolon
)               # end group 1
(               # start group 2
    [\s\S]+?    # 1 or more any character, not greedy
)               # end group 2
(               # start group 3
    \$link      # literally
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    =           # equal sign
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    ;           # semicolon
)               # end group 3
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]